# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable found in my Python Program

Tags: python

### Issue

I am trying to run a python program that shows a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. I am unable to resolve the error. Can someone help me out with this?

### Code

```py
import numpy as np
import tmm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nlambda = 1000
wavelengths = np.linspace(400,800,nlambda)
ns = np.linspace(1.48,1.48,nlambda)
ts = 500
na = 1.0
nf = np.linspace(1.217,1.217,nlambda)
thk = np.array([550/4/1.217])
q = 0.0*np.pi/180.0 
sp= 'TM'

back = 0
[T,R,t,r] = tmm (wavelengths,ns,ts,na,nf,thk,q,sp,back)
back = 1
    
[T,Rb,t,r] = tmm(wavelengths,ns,ts,na,nf,thk,q,sp,back)
np.savetxt('tmm_R_withwithout.data',np.transpose([wavelengths,R,Rb]))
plt.plot(wavelengths,R,wavelengths,Rb)
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
plt.ylabel('Reflection')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the full traceback

Comment: yeah, you really need to share the traceback. Python helped you now you help us. However... I don't know what `tmm` is, but `import tmm` means that its a module and `tmm (wavelengths,ns,ts,na,nf,thk,q,sp,back)` will raise that error. You need to look back at the `tmm` docs and figure out which function in `tmm` you should call.

Comment: Also, please give us some clarity on what you are trying to do with this program, and as another user suggested, please share the error traceback.

@tdelaney, from google, tmm - A transfer-matrix method optics package, for calculating reflection, transmission, absorption, and other relevant aspects of thin and thick multilayer (or single-layer) films

Comment: `import tmm` is importing `tmm` package/module and you are using it as if it were a function/callable. You probaby want some it's functions e.g. `tmm.coh_tmm`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.